Extracting images from a table column in a PDF and saving them to Excel

When using pdfplumber, I can't extract the images from a specific table column.
I use the following packages to get the images:
import fitz  # PyMuPDF
from PIL import Image

I need to use pdfplumber and above packages to place the images in the Excel rows as in the original PDF.
from flask import Flask, request, send_file, jsonify
import pdfplumber
import pandas as pd
import os
from flask_cors import CORS
import io
import fitz  # PyMuPDF
from PIL import Image
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image as ExcelImage
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return jsonify({'message': 'Welcome to the PDF to Excel converter API!'})


@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        return jsonify({'error': 'No file part'}), 400
    file = request.files['file']
    if file.filename == '':
        return jsonify({'error': 'No selected file'}), 400
    if file:
        # Ensure the 'uploads' directory exists
        if not os.path.exists('uploads'):
            os.makedirs('uploads')

        # Save the uploaded PDF file
        pdf_path = os.path.join('uploads', file.filename)
        file.save(pdf_path)

        # Extract tables and images, and save to Excel
        excel_path = pdf_path.replace('.pdf', '.xlsx')
        try:
            # Open the PDF file with pdfplumber
            with pdfplumber.open(pdf_path) as pdf:
                wb = Workbook()
                ws_data = wb.active
                ws_data.title = "Data"
                data_rows = []

                for page_num, page in enumerate(pdf.pages, start=1):
                    all_tables = []

                    # Extract tables from the current page
                    tables = page.extract_tables()
                    for table in tables:
                        df = pd.DataFrame(table)
                        all_tables.append(df)

                    if all_tables:
                        combined_df = pd.concat(all_tables, ignore_index=True)

                        if page_num == 1:  # Add headers only once for the first page
                            data_rows.extend(dataframe_to_rows(combined_df, index=False, header=True))
                        else:
                            data_rows.extend(dataframe_to_rows(combined_df, index=False, header=False))

                    # Open the PDF file with PyMuPDF to extract images
                    pdf_file = fitz.open(pdf_path)
                    output_dir = 'images'
                    os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)

                    # Extract images from the current page
                    page_mupdf = pdf_file[page_num - 1]  # Page index is 0-based
                    image_list = page_mupdf.get_images(full=True)

                    for img_index, img in enumerate(image_list):
                        xref = img[0]
                        base_image = pdf_file.extract_image(xref)
                        image_bytes = base_image["image"]
                        image_ext = base_image["ext"]
                        image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_bytes))

                        # Save the image
                        image_filename = f'{output_dir}/page_{page_num}_img_{img_index + 1}.{image_ext}'
                        image.save(image_filename)

                        # Create a new sheet for each image
                        ws_images = wb.create_sheet(title=f"Page_{page_num}_Image_{img_index + 1}")
                        img_excel = ExcelImage(image_filename)
                        ws_images.add_image(img_excel, 'A1')

                # Write all data rows to the 'Data' sheet
                for row in data_rows:
                    ws_data.append(row)

                # Save the Excel workbook
                wb.save(excel_path)

                return send_file(excel_path, as_attachment=True)

        except Exception as e:
            return jsonify({'error': str(e)}), 500


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if not os.path.exists('uploads'):
        os.makedirs('uploads')
    app.run(debug=True, port=2000, host='0.0.0.0')


(1) You can now import pymupdf directly - fitz is no longer needed. (2) You can use pymupdf for extracting tables on pages - no need using pdfplumber for this. (3) pymupdf's table finder directly supports pandas via table.to_pandas(). This results in a DataFrame which has all the pandas output options like Excel, CSV, JSON etc. Note: I am a maintainer and the original creator of PyMuPDF.

You can use pymupdf to find images and their boundary boxes - without using PIL or anything. Do images = [b for b in page.get_text("dict")["blocks"] if b["type"]==1] to extract all images. Then for each table cell check if any of the img["bbox"] is contained in the cell. If true use the img["image"] image binary to insert it in excel.

thank you so much for your response will try that and if i face any issues ill post please respond :D, thanks once again

As long as you're not asking about flask or web development, it would be appreciated if you could limit the code to the minimal amount needed to reproduce the issue.
